# How to get the maximum width of a single character in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fonts

How can I get the maximum width of a single character in JavaScript? I have a text painted in an unknown font, but I know what the text length and font size is.

Now I want the to get the largest character in that font, so I can make sure the parent element (a `div` for example) is not too narrow (it has an absolute width). The widest character is usually the M or W, but I'm not sure, perhaps there are fonts which paints wider characters.

Now how do I do that? Is there a fast method for?

Comment: When you say you have text 'painted' in an unknown font, do you mean it's an image?

Comment: No, I mean it's font is not set by CSS, so the system uses the default font.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CSS `width: 1em;`.  `em` is a relative measurement and is the width of the 'm' character

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that. But can you presume the 'm' is the widest character?

Comment: Technically, 1em is the point size of the current font and in modern typefaces is not necessarily the width of the 'M' character, although it was traditionally so.  One cannot assume that 'M' is the widest character in all typefaces.  In fact, there is _no_ standard widest character.  See [Em on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Em_(typography))